# Adding Style sheets to Angular 11 Application

Tags: css, angular

I created a new project using `ng new hello-world`.

After running the project using `ng serve` I am getting below source code from browser.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HelloWorld</title>
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" defer></script><script src="main.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

How `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` added here ?

How can I remove it ?

What should I do if I need to add another Style sheet like this one ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The CSS is automatically injected in your index.html by Angular. To remove this behavior, remove `styles.css` from `styles` in your angular.json file.

To add new styles, add the path to your other CSS in `styles`:

```
"styles": [
   "assets/css/custom-styles-1.css",
   "assets/css/custom-styles-2.css"
],
```

For more informations, check [Angular Workspace Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config).

Comment: Thanks @Xavier Brassoud. I tried like your way. I restarted build process again. But It is not working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7irPB.png   https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dUJI.png